# Use transformed iMac 27' to external display

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, mac

I converted my old iMac 27' to ubuntu 18.04 it works fine. Previously I used the iMac as an external display to my MacBook Pro 15' using the combination of **cmd+F2** and it worked.

Now I want to use the transformed iMac as an external display (notice that I don't have apple OS in parallel to the ubuntu) so the solution form:

1. [How to use iMac as external monitor for ubuntu laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637692/how-to-use-imac-as-external-monitor-for-ubuntu-laptop)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491594/reverse-engineering-the-target-display-mode-on-an-imac
3. https://floe.butterbrot.org/matrix/hacking/tdm/

Would appreciate some help

Comment: I have an iMac 27" mid 2011 (Model 12,2) and I'm trying to use target display functionality from linux OS. If your iMac 27" is older than middle 2011, it works with Florian research, but my Model12,2 doesn't work because SMC Registers don't exist. It maybe related to thunderbolt interface.